# bootstrap dropdown menu link to div content

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink, menu, contain

i want to make layout like this
[image]

I have a page, where in it there is a div. when click menu, then its contents will be displayed on the home page of this div. where the contents of each menu is another page (index.php/student,index.php/course etc)

how possible to create this layout with bootstrap?
anyone can help me?
thanks